# Knex.js insert works locally but not on Heroku deployment

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, knex.js

In my Express app, I want to create a new record when users send data via a post request. I have it working when I run it locally, but it doesn't work in the deployed site.

I am using knex.js. Here is the route that handles the post request:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
  newBook = {
    title: req.body.title,
    genre: req.body.genre,
    description: req.body.description,
    cover_url: req.body.cover_url
  }
  Books().insert(newBook, 'id').then(function(result) {
    res.send('Created new book with id ' + result)
  })
})
```

This is what is in the error logs on the deployed site:

`Unhandled rejection error: insert into "books" ("cover_url", "description", "genre", "title") values ($1, $2, $3, $4) returning "id" - duplicate key value violates unique constraint "books_pkey"`

On the local server, the request succeeds and I see the new record in the database. Any idea why this would be different? Thanks for any help! Let me know if other information would be useful.

- Deployed to Heroku
- node.js v4.2.1
- express v4.13.1
- knex v0.9.0
- pg v4.4.3

Comment: is the `id` field autoincrement?

Comment: I'm guessing, you didn't set up the database the same way locally and on Heroku. That could be the only reason.

Comment: How you solved this problem ?